# Print statements won't execute after the for loop

Tags: python

```
"""
ID: kunalgu1
LANG: PYTHON3
TASK: ride
"""
fin = open ('ride.in', 'r')

fout = open ('ride.out', 'w')
lines = fin.readlines()

cometString = lines[0]
cometValue = 1

groupString = lines[1]
groupValue = 1

def orderS (val):
    arrL = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] 
    arrN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
    indexVal = arrL.index(val.lower())
    return arrN[indexVal]

for x in cometString:
    print(orderS(x))
    cometValue *= orderS(x)
    print(cometValue)
```

Here is the main error: it won't print

```
cometValue = cometValue % 47
print(cometValue)

fout.close()
```

Comment: That's not possible, unless the loop is infinite. But `for x in cometString` isn't an infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you need `arrN`? Just return `arrL.index(val.lower()) + 1`

Comment: You can also use `return ord(val.lower()) - ord('a') + 1`

Comment: but does at nyone know why the statment wont print

Comment: Is this really your whole script?

Comment: When I try the script I get an error during the loop. `cometString` ends with a newline character, so it gets the error `ValueError: '\n' is not in list`.

Comment: how to do I fix the '\n' error

Comment: im new at python

Comment: And "fout" variable is doing nothing in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

The loop gets an error because the lines returned by `readlines()` include the newline terminator. When it calls `orderS()` for that character, `arrL.index()` fails because there's no newline in `arrL`.

You can remove the newline with the `rstrip()` method:

```
cometString = lines[0].rstrip()
```

You could also have `orderS()` return a default value when the character can't be found:

```
def orderS (val):
    arrL = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] 
    arrN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
    try:
        indexVal = arrL.index(val.lower())
        return arrN[indexVal]
    except ValueError:
        return 27
```

Comment: If you return 1 as a default value, he might think that val="a". So, 0 can be set as default, cuz he knows there is no 0 value in arrN variable :)

Comment: @Sherzod It;s multiplying the return values, if you multiply by 0 it will remain 0 forever.

Comment: @Sherzod This is calculating a hash, it's not intended to be reversable.

Comment: I've changed it to return `27` as the default, which isn't in `arrN`.

Comment: Then, he can check if it's 0. if(orderS(x) !=0): cometValue *= orderS(x). Something like this?

Comment: That's another way to do it. I wrote it this way to minimize the changes to the rest.